# argparser override set option manual

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible with argpaser in python to set the values without using command line, but using inline code. I'm working with an stitching example of opencv that uses it a lot, but i dont want that.
The image names in my situation are created by code, not by command line.
Its not only the images i like to set but several options as well so is there a common way to do this:

```
#in psuedo code
args = parser.parse_args()
args_setoption('images') = listToString(myimagelist)
```

Comment: Yes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method

Comment: `args.images=value`. Do a `print(args)` to see the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use argparse without command line using `parser.parse_args`:

```
import argparse


def listToString(myimagelist):
    return ' '.join(myimagelist)


myimagelist = ['/tmp/foo.png', '/tmp/bar.jpeg']

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test')
parser.add_argument('--images', type=str, help='(string) list of images')
_a = parser.parse_args([f'--images={listToString(myimagelist)}'])
print(_a.images)
```

Out:

```
/tmp/foo.png /tmp/bar.jpeg
```